# CSIDL constant for user folder for Windows XP

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-xp, windows-shell

I can't seem to find what is the CSIDL constant for "C:\Documents and Settings\username" folder for Windows XP?

EDIT: I'm retrieving this path using the following code:

```
HANDLE hUserToken = NULL;
if(WTSQueryUserToken(dwUserSessionID, &hUserToken))
{
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pIdl = NULL;
    if(SHGetFolderLocation(NULL, nCSIDL, hUserToken, NULL, &pIdl) == S_OK)
    {
        SHGetPathFromIDList(pIdl, path_buf);

        ILFree(pIdl);
    }

    CloseHandle(hUserToken);
}
```

The issue becomes that the code returns `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile` for an administrative account when I'm expecting `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @K-ballo: OK. I found that myself. But which constant am I supposed to use?

Comment: An alternative function is [GetUserProfileDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I would expect it to return the same result.

Comment: @Luke: Aha! You got my friend! Thanks. Do you want to post it as an answer? It actually returned the expected result. Evidently that is why they introduced that API.

Answer (score 1):

Check this reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The constant you are looking for is `CSIDL_PROFILE`.

Comment: Nope, it won't work. I tried it on XP and I get "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile" when it's supposed to be "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator"

Comment: I'm getting it by calling `SHGetFolderLocation` with a user token that I get from `WTSQueryUserToken` that I get from a user's session ID. In Windows XP there's no session isolation, so session ID is 0, which is the same as the services session. Maybe that's why it returns such result ... But that doesn't help with my original question.

Comment: @user843732: Your original question is what is the _CSIDL profile_ question, while your **actual** question appears to be how to get the path to the administrator profile

Comment: Well, I need it to work for any user account, not just the admin.

Comment: Am I safe to do, say, `CSIDL_APPDATA` and then strip out `Application Data` from the end?

Comment: OK, then. Any idea how to do it? Again, I don't need it specifically for an admin account. It's just that it fails for it.

Comment: Because Session 0 Isolation does not exist in XP, the user account that is running Session 0 is a system account, not a user account. As such, you are retrieving the wrong token when `dwUserSessionId` is 0. For Session 0 only, instead of using WTSQueryUserToken(), you need to enumerate the user processes running in Session 0, such as explorer.exe, until you find one running as the user you are interested in, then extract the user token from that process.

Answer (score 0):

- Code snippet to obtain locations: [ConstantSpecialItems.cpp](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ConstantSpecialItems/ConstantSpecialItems.cpp) + binary [ConstantSpecialItems.exe](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ConstantSpecialItems/Release/ConstantSpecialItems.exe) if you want to print them yourself
- Sample Locations:

  - [Windows XP](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ConstantSpecialItems/Release/Windows%20version%205.1%2C%20Build%202600.txt)
  - [Windows Vista](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ConstantSpecialItems/Release/Windows%20version%206.0%2C%20Build%206002.txt)
  - [Windows 7](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ConstantSpecialItems/Release/Windows%20version%206.1%2C%20Build%207600.txt)

The one you ask for:

```
Windows version 5.1, Build 2600

CSIDL paths: 
[...] 
CSIDL_PROFILE: C:\Documents and Settings\John Doe
```

Comment: As I noted in my conversation with @K-ballo `CSIDL_PROFILE` may return an unexpected result for an Administrator account on Windows XP. As it turns out calling `GetUserProfileDirectory` solves the issue.